# Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression for loader.gl In a Next13 typescript application

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, deck.gl, next.js13

I've set up a Next13 typescript application. Inside this i'm attempting to render a deckgl arclayer on top of a Mapbax base map.

```
const Page = () => {
  const data = [{ sourcePosition: [-122.41669, 37.7853], targetPosition: [-122.41669, 37.781] }];
  const isClient = typeof window !== 'undefined';

  const layer = isClient
    ? new ArcLayer({
        id: 'arc-layer',
        migration,
        pickable: true,
        getWidth: (d: AreaMigration) => d.moves_estimated / 10,
        getSourcePosition: (d: AreaMigration) => states[d.origin_us_state],
        getTargetPosition: (d: AreaMigration) => states[d.destination_us_state],
        //@ts-ignore
        getSourceColor: (d: AreaMigration) => [...hexToRgb(Primary.Primary01), 255],
        //@ts-ignore
        getTargetColor: (d: AreaMigration) => [...hexToRgb(Secondary.Secondary01), 125],
      })
    : undefined;

  return (
    <MapboxPageStyled>
      {isClient && (
        <DeckGL
          initialViewState={INITIAL_VIEW_STATE}
          controller={true}
          style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', borderRadius: '3px', overflow: 'hidden' }}
          layers={[layer]}
        >
          <ReactMapGL />
        </DeckGL>
      )}
      <Paragraph>{migration[0].origin_area}</Paragraph>
    </MapboxPageStyled>
  );
};
```

Upon building the page I get the error
`warn  - ./node_modules/@loaders.gl/worker-utils/dist/es5/lib/node/require-utils.node.js Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression`

I've modified the next-config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  experimental: { appDir: true, esmExternals: 'loose' },
  transpilePackages: ['@loaders.gl', '@probe.gl'],
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

and enabled clientside rendering on the page already.

All help appreciated!

I've also tried using the dynamic import functionality on both the arclayer and deckgl with no success.

Answer (score 2):

A [workaround I found on Github](https://github.com/Thopiax/batch11_e_cartomobile_ui/blob/18b955287fa7b36f6dc8a6f450232ae98c77709a/next.config.js#L19) that suppresses the error:

```js
// next.config.js
const nextConfig = {
  ...
  webpack: (config) => {
    ...

    // Fixes warning Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
    config.module = {
      ...config.module,
      exprContextCritical: false,
    };

    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on which I spent a lot of time. Just downgrade @loaders.gl, which causes problems to the 3.1.8 version.

If you're using npm, add the next overrides to your `package.json`:

```
  "overrides": {
    "@loaders.gl/core": "3.1.8",
    "@loaders.gl/images": "3.1.8",
    "@loaders.gl/3d-tiles": "3.1.8",
    "@loaders.gl/gis": "3.1.8",
    "@loaders.gl/textures": "3.1.8",
    "@loaders.gl/terrain": "3.1.8",
    "@loaders.gl/schema": "3.1.8",
    "@loaders.gl/gltf": "3.1.8",
    "@loaders.gl/tiles": "3.1.8",
    "@loaders.gl/loader-utils": "3.1.8"
  }
```

After that, just delete your `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json`

Good luck :)